# Ignore extraneous commas when using pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I'm working with an open data set that records the enrolment in schools from 1999 to 2015.  However, the data set has pre-allocated columns in the CSV for future years even though those columns are empty.

The data can be viewed at http://www.gov.pe.ca/opendata/OD9%20Offical%20School%20Enrollments%201999%20-2015.csv

This is my code:

```
#Read current open data set (OD34) from URL and store in an array called enrollment
url = "http://www.gov.pe.ca/opendata/OD9%20Offical%20School%20Enrollments%201999%20-2015.csv?"
col_names = ['School_Name','1999','2000','2001','2002','2003','2004','2005','2006','2007','2008','2009','2010','2011','2012','2013','2014','2015']
enrollment = pandas.read_csv(url, header=None, skiprows=1, names=col_names, nrows=2)
print(enrollment)
print(enrollment.shape)
print(type(enrollment))
```

The code does turn values, but the excessive commas means there are dozens of NaN values for each school.  The DataFrame does show as a 2,18 array but `print(enrollment)` shows the NaN values.

EDIT:  I added `na_filter=False` to the pandas.read_csv statement and the extraneous NaN values are gone when I `print(enrollment)` but it looks like every column (a year) has all of the data instead of aligning each year's enrollment figure.

Here is an example of the data.

```
School Name,1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
Alberton Elementary School,229,231,237,213,225,218,219,214,194,186,167,175,178,158,148,129,127,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Comment: Is the [dropna](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) DataFrame method what you're looking for?

Comment: I could definitely drop the NA post-import using dropna.  See my edit where I use 'na_filter=False' to achieve the same result.

Comment: `enrollment.dropna(axis=1)`

Comment: Again, what is your question?

Comment: @piRSquared At first I was trying to figure out how to exclude the extraneous NaN values (that seems to be solved using na_filter=False) but now I am trying to ensure that the values for each column are being parsed correctly.  I doesn't seem to be the case given the results I see when I 'print(enrollment)' but since today is my very first time trying to use Pandas and last week was my very first attempt at using Python I'm not exactly sure to be honest.

Comment: @jbiggley I don't thing `na_filter` is doing what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd parse it like this:

```
pandas.read_csv(url, index_col=0).filter(regex='\d{4}')
```

Looks like this

[image]

---

***What its doing***

- `index_col=0` tells pandas that the first column is the index.  This seems reasonable and after looking at the results, it feels right.
- By default, `read_csv` will assume there is a header row.  Let it.
- `filter(regex='\d{4}')` is only going to pass columns with headers that are four digits.

---

So make sure you assign it to the dataframe variable you want.

```
enrollment = pandas.read_csv(url, index_col=0).filter(regex='\d{4}')
```

Comment: Awesome! The .filter(regex='\d{4}') is exactly what I was looking for in the solution.  Thanks!  Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation for my vote show up, but I did up vote your answer.

Comment: @jbiggley No worries.  Happy New Year!